# Django CheckboxSelectMultiple widget : render only selected data by default

Tags: html, django

Greeting, I have a manytomany field call `user` in my `model_A` model, in my form, how can I  display only the list of selected data associated to the `model_A` by default instead of listing entire entries from the `User` model in my html page? my intention is to create a setting page where I can remove the user associated to a project

below is my code :

model.py :

```
class model_A(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
```

form.py :

```
class EditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    prefix = 'edit_form'
    class Meta:
        model = model_A
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {'user':forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple}
```

html :

```
<div class="field">
    {{form.user}}
</div>
```

Any help is much appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change user queryset inside `__init__` method of *EditForm* class.

```
class EditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    prefix = 'edit_form'
    class Meta:
        model = model_A
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {'user':forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple}

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.event = kwargs.pop('event')
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        # replace dots with your conditions in filter
        self.fields['user'].queryset = self.user.filter(...)
```

**UPDATE**

List users that are associated with `Model_A`

```
self.fields['user'].queryset = self.user.all()
```

Comment: Hi @Satendra, thanks for your reply this is what I'm looking for, can you give me an syntax example for the condition, I'm trying to do it myself, but its not working, apologies, I'm still new in python. I'll update my code above

Comment: Check my update, to show users that are associated to `Model_A` just write `.all()` instead of `.filter()`